# Invalid argument for foreach... to a global $var;

Tags: php, foreach, arguments, global

```
$form[0]= '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
        <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
        <body>';
        $form[1]= '<div class="logo img-center"></div><div class="box-shadow fondo-blanco">';
        $form[2]= '<p class="mostrar caja texto-advertencia">Para acceder a este sitio debes iniciar sesión nuevamente.</p>';
        $form[3]= '<form method="post" action="" class="caja borde-transparente " style="margin: 14px auto;width:400px;max-width:100%;">';
        $form[4]='<span class="mostrar texto-advertencia p">
        <a href="javascript: window.history.go(-1)" class="i-cerrar float-right"></a>
        Clave o nombre de usuario incorrectos! <br> Debes iniciar sesión con una cuenta con acceso de administrador para ver este contenido.</span>';
        $form[5]='<span class="mostrar texto-advertencia p">Haz realizado demasiados intentos fallidos para iniciar la sesión. Intentá nuevamente en unos minutos.';
        $form[6]=    '<label class="borde-identidad texto-gris-oscuro caja-i caja con-separador m con-relieve-3"><span class="i-storekey"></span>Iniciar sesión:</label>
            <input class="input borde-gris" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" name="username" autofocus>
            <input class="input borde-gris" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password">';
        $form[7]=    '<div class="checkbox" style="font-size:16px">
                <input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" name="remember-me" value="1">
                <label for="mycheckbox" class="texto-gris-oscuro"> Mantener la sesión iniciada
                </label>
            </div>';
        $form[8]= '<input type="submit" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-info">
          </form></body></html>';
if (!function_exists('echo_formulario')){
    function echo_formulario($rough=NULL){
    global $form;
    foreach ($form as $key=>$html):
        #some code here...
    endforeach;
    }
}
```

The foreach loop gives an "invalid argument" warning. It worked on localhost yesterday though...

*Is there a problem in the way the `$form` var is being called?*

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: `$html` is not defined in your code.

Problem 2: There is a colon `:` at the end of your foreach

Problem 3: A lot of your opening brackets `{` do not have a closing bracket

Try this first

```
if (!function_exists('echo_formulario')){
    function echo_formulario($rough=NULL){
        global $form;
        foreach ($form as $key=>$html){
            echo $key;
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work try using `foreach ($form as $key)` instead.

```
if (!function_exists('echo_formulario')){
    function echo_formulario($rough=NULL){
        global $form;
        foreach ($form as $key){
            echo $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Hey david, the post above was updated, I cropped the code to avoid making the post just too long.I tried both replacing the **´foreach():
 endforeach;´** for a **´foreach(){ }´** and also changin the statement to ´foreach ($form as $key){´ )